# preg_match_all - how to catch all subpatterns

Tags: php, regex, regular-language

A have this:

```
$pattern = "/\b(?:(one|two|three|four|five|(?:s|z)ix|seven|eight|nine|zero|twelve)(?:\s|-)*){4,8}/ix";
$subject = "one  four-six  nine  twelve
zero eight nine  nine seven three six six";
$matches = [];

preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

What I want to see is all separated words in `$matches` but I getting only nine for first and six for second - last words of big pattern. I know I can put all single words in brackets, but is there any more good way + I will get empty strings that way

Output like:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'one  four-six  nine  twelve
zero eight nine  ' (length=46)
      1 => string 'one'
      2 => string 'four' 
      3 => string 'six' 
      4 => string 'nine' 
      5 => string 'twelve' 
      6 => string 'zero' 
      7 => string 'eight' 
      8 => string 'nine' 
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'nine seven three six six' (length=24)
      ...
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your expected output.

Comment: Are you looking for [something like this](http://ideone.com/O5pZb0)?

Comment: Nope. I added output as I expecting

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to match all of your numbers and added a named group called **number**:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/\b(?<number>one|two|three|four|five|(?:s|z)ix|seven|eight|nine|zero|twelve)(?:\s|-)/';
$subject = "one  four-six  nine  twelve
zero eight nine  nine seven three six six";
$matches = [];

preg_match_all ($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

This has twelve (all) results. See a demo on regex101.com [here](https://regex101.com/r/iG5lG9/1).

Comment: Nah, they was grouped from 4 to 8 for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to see is all separated words in `$matches` but I getting
>   only nine for first and six for second - last words of big pattern.

Unfortunately, that's the way it is, as stated for [Repetition](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php):

> When a capturing subpattern is repeated, the value captured is the
>   substring that matched the final iteration.

---

> I know I can put all single words in brackets, but is there any more
>   good way…

One approach is to split the found matches afterwards:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as &$m)
    // replace $m[1] with the split match
    array_splice($m, 1, 1, preg_split('/\s|-/', $m[0], 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
unset($m);  // remove the reference to the last element
```

This will yield the desired result in `$matches`.